# Is there any way to start learning Real Analysis without any grasp of calculus?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, reference-request

Firstly, i have nothing against learning it in the conventional way. But my situation is very specific, i'm currently studying Computer Seience, and my university simply skipped calculus, we had no classes until now (and we are never having it at all), and my time is simply limited (impossibly limited) to learn everything before the start of analysis itself.

I know most universities get deeply into calculus (at least) beforehand, and that real analysis apparently *includes* calculus into it, but my resources or ideas on how to learn it that way are simply nonexistent,and i'm not really certain if it's possible. Every book i find requires calculus, and treats Real Analysis as a formalization of Calculus, apparently restudying it as one of the topics, in a (obviously) formalized way.

If confirmed as possible, are there any books specifically, or adequately useful for this? And which are the prerequisites for it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Spivak's *Calculus* doesn't assume any prior knowledge of calculus: all the applications to things like extrema, areas, arc lengths and so on are incorporated. (And despite the name, it's one of the best introductory analysis books.)

Comment: I've readed about it in another question (curiously similar to mine), BUT i was really uncertain if it didn't required any prior knowledge of "Higher level calculus" or calculus by itself. You may have saved my life right now. How grateful.

Comment: I was about to give the same answer. What it DOES require is an ability to do a proof (and know when you've got it right). it also requires familiarity with what I'd call Algebra I and II: graphing, knowing about functions (what's the domain of a function, what's the codomain (or 'range' in some books), what's the image), finding roots of quadratics, knowing a little bit about sines and cosines, inverse functions and their graphs, factoring low-degree polynomials, basic inequalities, 'completing the square'). If you've got that, you're good to go.

Comment: The first edition is available for free [here](https://archive.org/details/Calculus_643). (There's also an answer book available.) If *Calculus* proves too advanced, there's [this](http://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/a-hitchhikers-guide-to-the-calculus), also by Spivak, that I haven't read, but the reviewer seems to think it works reasonably well.

Comment: Consider yourself lucky. IMHO it is a sin to study calculus without proofs (and defer proofs to a later course in Real analysis). Grab a copy of Hardy's *A Course of Pure Mathematics* 10th edition (should be available freely online if you search enough). It is especially written for self study and you will forget the difference between calculus and analysis.

Comment: Analysis and calculus are the same thing in mathematical terms, but in some education systems they are treated as separate subjects, in which "calculus" deals with the more elementary parts. Conversely, in other countries (e.g., France), everything is called "analysis." How this division is drawn (if at all) depends on each country. If you can include the syllabus for your course here, then people will be able to tell you whether its level corresponds to what would be called "calculus" or "analysis" in the U.S., and what books would best correspond to that syllabus.

Comment: I would recommend Apostol Calculus Vol 1. It is a calculus book/analysis lite, or you could read Ross' Elementary Analysis. As stated above, analysis is calculus, except analysis is more proof of why this or that vs. computations.